Video/Audio calling SDKs with ad placement facility
I need to display ADs on the call receiver node of my application
I am looking for a video/audio call SDK (Agora, Twilio, videosdk, Jitsi etc..), which will provide additional functionality to display ADs on the call receiver node

Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask] - Asking recommendations on libraries, frameworks, etc. is off-topic here

All of these services providers do not provide native functionality to display ads. you can use your custom logic to display ads.
FYI: Twilio has announced End of Life (EOL) notice to their Programmable Video product
